# change placing of child views dynamically using onDraw?

Tags: android, android-custom-view, viewgroup

Is there a way to dynamically change the position(like a manually translation animation) on a child view thats been defined and places inside onLayout?

i have this onLayout defined here:

```
  @Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {

        //place topview at the top of the layout by removing the ySpace value defined fro the height
        // of this view and dividing the height so that the topView takes nearly half the space
        // height of this view container
        topView.layout(0, 0, getWidth(), (getHeight() - ySpace) / 2);
    }
```

i want to manually change the y axis position of topView Dynamically .

i was thinking ofabout onDraw but onDraw doesnt that childViews and draws them. Instead it just gives you a blank canvas to manually draw items in it.

Currently implementing a custom ViewGroup that takes x amount of child views and dynamically moves them around. My question is how do i move them around?

Comment: when you wanr to change the position call requesrLayout and then onLayout will be caled where you layout() each child View

Comment: Ok i will see if that works